# Vivado "Export hardware" packs unknown bitstream

Tags: xilinx, vivado, zynq, xilinx-sdk

We have a Zynq project in Vivado 2017.4. I can generate the bitstream, in `proj/proj.runs/impl_1/mybitstream.bit`.

Then I want to import that configuration to my petalinux project so I use `File > Export > Export Hardware...`, make sure the `Include bitstream` is checked and keep the the `Export location: <local to project>` (which ends up in `proj/proj.sdk`).

That gives me a `proj/proj.sdk/proj.hdf` file, but when I unzip it, file `mybitstream.bit` is *not* the one in `proj.runs/impl_1`! (it actually is one from a previous build).

I have to import hardware description then manually overwrite the old bitstream:

```
$ petalinux-config --get-hw-description=proj/proj.sdk
$ cp proj/proj.runs/impl_1/mybitstream.bit petalinux-proj/project-spec/hw-description/
```

Does anybody know *where* the `Export hardware` function gets the bitstream? Maybe there is a way to "clean" a Vivado project? (there is no such option in Vivado).
So far we only modified logic in the PL but I fear that, when we add some BRAM or change some addresses, the whole hardware description will be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the same on [Xilinx Forum](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/Where-does-Vivado-get-the-files-to-generate-hdf/m-p/883768) and I think it could be an issue with Vivado not properly cleaning the `.sysdef` file in `proj.runs/impl_1/`.

After manually deleting it and re-generating the bitstream (which was fast because most of it was already compiled), the export gave me the proper `.hdf`.